# Conditional Probability [10]

Tags: probability

[image]

I have been trying to solve this question for quite some time. The first part is trivial, however, I am having trouble with the second part. The question has to do with conditional probability, but I am not sure with summing up a product of probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

The numerator is $P(X>10, X+Y>40)$, where $X$ is the number of birds seen on Monday, and $Y$ is the number seen from Tuesday through Sunday. These are assumed independent. You can write out the numerator by specifying what value $X$ can take:
$$
\begin{align}
P(X>10, X+Y>40)&=\sum_{r=11}^\infty P(X=r, X+Y>40)\\
&=\sum_{r=11}^\infty P(X=r, Y>40-r)\\
&\stackrel{(1)}=\sum_{r=11}^\infty P(X=r)P(Y>40-r)\\
&\stackrel{(2)}=\sum_{r=11}^{40} P(X=r)P(Y>40-r)+\sum_{r=41}^\infty P(X=r)P(Y>40-r)
\end{align}
$$
We use independence in (1). In (2) we split up the sum at the boundary point $r=40$, because if $r>40$ then $40-r$ is negative, so $P(Y>40-r)=1$. This explains the final form that you see.